# How to handle resource changes after provider upgrade in terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider

I am trying to upgrade the `azurerm` terraform provider from `2.30.0` to `3.13.0`. For sure there are several changes in some resources (e.g. resoruce name changes, renamed attributes, removed attributes, etc.). I checked the [Azure Resource Manager Upgrade Guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/3.0-upgrade-guide) and found those changes by which our configuration is affected.

For example in version `3.0.0` the attribute `availibility_zones` is replaced by `zones` for the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool` ressource. Therefore when i run `terraform plan` i get an error, that the attribute `availibility_zones` doesn't exists.

I found a [migration guide from deprecated resources](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/migrating-from-deprecated-resources). I understood the idea of removing the resource from the state and importing it again by it's resource id, but there are also other resources like `azurerm_subnet`, `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster`, `azurerm_storage_account` they have resource changes, why the `terraform import -var-file='./my.tfvars' [..]` command fails.

I am not sure if it fails (only) because of the dependencies to some variables they are needed for declaring the resource properly. Or would it also fail because of reading the  `.tfvars` and terraform compares the read variables with the state?

Actually i need a "best practice" guide how to handle resource changes after a provider update. I dont know where to start and where to end. I tried to visualize the dependencies with `terraform graph` and created a `svg` to try to figure out the order by which i have to migrate the resource changes. It's unpossible to understand the relations of the whole configuration.. I could also just remove attributes from the state file they doesnt exists anymore, or rename attributes manually.

So **How to handle resource changes after provider upgrade in terraform?**

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT Hi, it doesnt. I wrote that i knew that already. I would like to ask a concrete question. You are using a resource `x` that has the attribute named `abc` that is renamed to `cab`. And you dont are using that attribute actively in your terraform code, it is just with his default value in the statefile. Then you upgrade `azurerm` and `init`. Now when you `plan`, then the `azurerm` can't parse the attribute `abc` because in the provider it is named `cab` and you are not using it in your terraform code. How you handle this?

Comment: FYI there is no need to ever ask people to accept an answer. Also, @bilal32 - if you have additional questions, either revise your post, or ask a new question. Please don't ask new questions inside of a comment.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Hi, thanks for your advice. Actually it is not a new question. It's part of this question. I wanted to concretise it a bit, to come then to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### General

I was able to update the provider properly - i hope at least. I would like to share my experience, maybe it would help other beginners. **This is not a professional guide, but just my experience that i want to share.**

First of all you have to remove **ALL** resources affected by the provider upgrade and then re-import them. What does that mean?

The new provider will contain divers changes on different resources. For example:

- Removed deprecated attributes (attribute is completely removed)
- Superseded attribute (attribute is replaced by another).
- Renamed attributes
- Superseded resources (here the resource can be deprecated or removed by the upgraded version)

#### **Note**

[The migration guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/migrating-from-deprecated-resources) describes how you can migrate from deprecated resources, but the workflow for attribute changes is the same. How i understood it. This is the only guide that i found.

`terraform plan` will show you one or several errors for affected resources.

If your terraform configuration is complex and huge, then you shouldn't try to remove and re-import them all at once. Just go step by step and fix one affected resource successively.

`terraform plan` can show changes although he shouldn't.

- Check the `force replacement` attribute accurately and understand why terraform detects changes. It's seems be obvious but it doesn't have to.
- There can be a type change e.g. int -> string
- If the affected change is a kind of missing secret, then you can try to add the secret manually as the value to the related attribute in the `state` file and run `terraform plan` again.
- Or there can be also a bug by the provider. So if you can't understand the detected change try to search the issues of the provider - mostly on github. Don't get confused if you can't find any related issue, maybe you have found a bug. Then just create a new issue.

You will also face some other errors or bugs related to terraform itself. You have to search for a workaround patiently, so that you can continue apply the resource changes.

Try to figure out resource changes or to ignore an error for this moment that occurs in another module with [resource targeting](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/plan#resource-targeting).

#### How To

1. **---> !! BACKUP YOUR STATE FILE !! <---**: You have to backup your state file before you start manipulating the `state` file. You will be able to restore the state of the backed state file if something goes wrong. Also you can use the backed up `state` file for finding needed `id`s when you have to import the resource.
2. **Get Affected Resource:**
   How you can find all affected resources? After the upgrade the provider will not be able to parse the `state` file, if a resource contains changes - like i described in the question above. You will get an error for affected resources. Then you can check the changes for this affected resource in the upgrade guide of the provider - can be found in the provider register e.g. [azurerm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/3.0-upgrade-guide).
3. **Terraform Configuration:** Now you have to apply the changes for the affected resources in the terraform configuration modules before you can import them like described in [the migration guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/migrating-from-deprecated-resources).
4. **Remove Outdated Resource**: Like described in the [the migration guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/migrating-from-deprecated-resources) you have to remove the outdated resource from the `state` file because it contains the old format of the resource. The new provider is not able to handle these resources from the `state` file. They must be re-imported with the new provider.
5. **Import Removed Resource**: After you removed the resource you have to re-import it also described in [the migration guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/migrating-from-deprecated-resources). Check the [terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import) documentation for better understanding and usage.

Comment: Where did you find this guide?

Comment: @AnthonyKlotz I've created this

Answer (score -1):

> So How to handle resource changes after provider upgrade in terraform?

I don't think deleting the `state` file and then importing the resource and do changes in resources attribute based on when you require to upgrade the azurerm version is a feasible solution.

Terraform Registry already given update/notes for every resource when they did some changes on their upgrading version. Just like below example

we use `azurerm_app_service` for version ~2.x but for version ~3.0 and ~4.0 `azurerm_linux_web_app` and `azurerm_windows_web_app` resources instead.

[image]

Would suggest you check the terraform registry for update on particular resources attribute for specific provider version or not and do it accordingly.

Comment: You can use the new resources easily when you just starting. But when you have a configuration already, then "how to migrate your existing configuration to the new resources?". I upgraded the provider version and did a `terraform plan`. Of course the resources in the state file are described based on the previous version of the provider. There will be attributes and resources they don't exists in the new version anymore - like I described above. You answer dont helped me yet, I already described that. I need a "hands-on", "how-to", "best-practise" etc. "guide", "tutorial"..

Comment: If you change the provider version . you need to do terraform init to intialize the upgraded version in your state file and morever terraform works on incremental order so what ever you will change in resource attribute and do plan and apply it will replace the old terraform state attribute with new attribute of same resource.

Comment: For me it don't replaced anything automatically. I get an error, that resource x couldn't be parsed/read from the resource file because attribute `availibility_zones` doesn't exist - as an example. Therefore Microsoft described a workaround how to migrate it by removing the resource from the state and import it again. But there are more related changes why it is not obvious how to it correctly. Im confused why I can't find any accurate guide in the internet how to it. Also that nobody really answers this questions shows, that isn't well documented and known in the community I think.